# How to add href to Wicket DataTable cells

Tags: java, wicket

I have simple DataTable with ListDataProvider.
HTML markup is as simple as `<table wicket:id="data"/>`.
I need to open other page with query string to display form for single selected item.
How to add links (a href) to cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actual answer I found at official doc https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Adding+links+in+a+DefaultDataTable